# Design for application able to calculate a function or load the result from a file

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I have many files that I need to process with certain time-consuming functions f_1() ... f_n().
Because of this, I tought to save the fk_processed_output in a file every time a function f_k() ends its work, in order to avoid recalculation in future work sessions.

The program has to be able to choose dynamically if it need to calculate the result or to load it from HDD (if it was calculated in a previous time for the given input file).

What may be a good design to implement this?

I thought to implement every f_k{} like this:

```
def f_k():
    if (fk_processed_output.exist()):
        load_it_from_file()
    else:
        output = do_some_stuff()
    save_to_file(output)
```

but I don't like it very much because of the repetion of the if/else pattern for each function.

Any better or clever idea? Any other hint? Does exist any library for such a purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a decorator:

```
def fk_processed (fk):
    filename = fk.__name__ + '_output.json'
    def new_fk (*args, **kargs):
        if (os.path.exists(filename)):
            print("Load from file (" + fk.__name__ + ").")
            output = json.load (open(filename))
        else:
            print("Call to function (" + fk.__name__ + ").")
            output = fk (*args, **kargs)
            json.dump (output, open(filename, 'w'))
        return output
    return new_fk

@fk_processed
def f1 (): 
    ...

@fk_processed
def f2 ():
    ...

>>> f1 ()
Call to function (f1).
>>> f1 ()
Load from file (f1).
```

I used `json` for storing data so you don't have (most of the time) to worry about the type of the values returned by the `fk`.

Note that this does not work if the output of your `fk` is not always the same. In this case you have to add some extra stuff to `fk_processed`.

---

Here is a  version that works with arguments but not with keyword arguments (you can modify it if you want, simply always consider keywords arguments in the same order... ). Do not use it if you don't have very heavy function!

```
def fk_processed (fk):
    filename = fk.__name__ + '_output.json'
    def new_fk (*args):
        store = {}
        if (os.path.exists(filename)):
            store = json.load (open(filename))
        cstore = store
        i = 0
        while i < len(args) and str(args[i]) in cstore:
            cstore = cstore[str(args[i])]
            i += 1
        if i != len(args):
            while i < len(args) - 1:
                cstore[str(args[i])] = {}
                cstore = cstore[str(args[i])]
                i += 1
            # print('compute')
            cstore[str(args[i])] = fk (*args)
            cstore = cstore[str(args[i])]
            json.dump (store, open(filename, 'w'))
        return cstore
    return new_fk
```

Note that I am converting the arguments to string in the `store` dictionnary because JSON allows only string as keys. This can break lot of things if your function arguments are not simple.

Example:

```
>>> @fk_processed
... def add (x, y): return x + y
...
>>> add (1, 2)
compute
3
>>> add (1, 3)
compute
4
>>> add (1, 2)
3
>>> add ('1', '3') # Here is the problem if you can have various types from your arguments
4 # expected '13'
```